# Run Multiple Terminals For Kafka Insite Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I want to run "standalone" Docker container with a configured Kafka server.
I found out on Kafka website (https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) how to run Kafka topic:) 
But when I'm doing everything as instructed I need to run three terminals:

One for run ZooKeeper server:

```
 ./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Second for start kafka server:

```
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Third for create a topic:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

The question is :
How do I run three independent terminals inside Docker while building the  docker image?
Because 1 want to only use commands:

```
docker build . -t kafka
```

and then

```
docker start kafka
```

and have an up and running Kafka server with a created topic.
I done something but I stack on trying to create this terminals. 
Here's the project:

> https://github.com/mpawel1993/Kafka-Docker

Comment: Why do you need terminal windows at all?  You should have two separate containers, one each for ZooKeeper and Kafka, and you'll probably need to manually create the topic on first startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to run "standalone" Docker container with a configured Kafka server

If you want a configured Kafka server, any of the existing Docker images work fine. landoop/fast-data-dev includes both Kafka, Zookeeper, Kafka Connect, and a Schema Registry, if by "standalone" you mean have all necessary components in one image

> How do I run three independent terminals inside Docker while building the docker image

You wouldn't. Each RUN command its a single terminal

You also should not start Kafka and Zookeeper in one container for fault tolerance and scalability reasons

You also don't need to create Kafka topics while *building* the container, only once the container is built and server is running can you create topics